# HTML - local testing with DocType set

Tags: html, testing, browser, doctype

I have a website with that header in the pages :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

When testing pages on a computer which is internet connected, everything is fine.

When testing the same page without internet connection, the page design is rendered awfully !!!

How may I set the doctype to let the browser know what kind of doctype my pages are made for, and be able to see the pages well on a non-connected computer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, it was because of the following HTML comment style that was put in different places in the HTML file :

```
<!-- ------------------ Some comment to organize HTML code ---------------- -->
```

Answer (score 2):

The URL has no in the Doctype has no effect regarding rendering of pages in browsers.

Whatever is causing you problems with your off-line rendering, it has nothing to do with the Doctype.

Most likely, you are depending on images or stylesheets with URIs on the Internet and the browser cannot retrieve them without the connection.

Comment: No, everything is local... Everything. Just removing the doctype solves the problem with no connection available. So the problem IS the doctype statement.

Answer (score 1):

The doctype you use is one of the doctypes that causes “standards mode” (as opposite to “quirks mode”) in browsers—google for "quirks mode" to find some basic info on this phenomenon, which can affect rendering in many ways, even dramatically.

Assuming you want “standards mode;” such a doctype is what you can do. Browsers may still display the page in “quirks mode” if instructed to. I suspect that you might be testing on IE with settings that make it display all local documents (“all intranet pages”) in “quirks mode” (“compatibility view”). In that case, it’s not a problem with the page but with browser settings.

Comment: Puzzling... but the puzzle might have a solution if we knew the URL. I started suspecting that this is not a quirks mode issue but related to character encodings. Perhaps the page does not declare its encoding in markup but the server sends suitable encoding information in HTTP headers.